# Execute SandboxPostCopy Interface from Anonymous Window

Tags: apex, sandboxpostcopy

How can we execute SandboxPostCopy Interface from Anonymous Window for testing purpose.

```
global class PrepareMySandbox implements SandboxPostCopy {
    global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {
        System.debug('Org ID: ' + context.organizationId());
        System.debug('Sandbox ID: ' + context.sandboxId());
        System.debug('Sandbox Name: ' + context.sandboxName());

        // Insert logic here to prepare the sandbox for use.
    }
}
```

Comment: Typically, you'd write a Unit Test for testing purposes.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out `SandboxContext` is an interface you can implement.  If you want to execute against a non-null context, you can do a mock implementation in your execute anonymous window:

```
public class MockSandboxContext implements SandboxContext
{
    public ID organizationID(){return '00D200000001111';}
    public ID sandboxID(){return '00D200000001112';}
    public ID sandboxName(){return '00D200000001113';}
}

public class MockSandboxCopy implements SandboxPostCopy
{
    public void runApexClass(SandboxContext context)
    {
        System.debug('Org ID: ' + context.organizationId());
        System.debug('Sandbox ID: ' + context.sandboxId());
        System.debug('Sandbox Name: ' + String.valueOf(context.sandboxName()));
        //For some reason the above line throws an UnexpectedException with the message
        //"Unexpected Arguments" if you do not use String.valueOf
    }
}

SandboxContext context = new MockSandboxContext();
new MockSandboxCopy().runApexClass(context);
```

Comment: This method isn't outlined in the documentation, and is thus subject to not work in the future (unless it's added to the documentation). That said, that's a pretty awesome hack. Hopefully they add it to the documentation and make it official.

Comment: This is great!  One minor correction, in the MockSandboxContext class, shouldn't sandboxName be defined as a String instead of an ID?

Comment: @MikePaisner That would make sense, it would explain why I was getting an exception accessing it.  I am not working in Salesforce anymore though so I can't validate it, in the developer console you may be able to pull up the interface definition.  IIRC interface methods that are defined as returning ID can be implemented as returning string anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
global class PrepareMySandbox implements SandboxPostCopy {
    global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {
        if (context != null) {
          System.debug('Org ID: ' + context.organizationId());
          System.debug('Sandbox ID: ' + context.sandboxId());
          System.debug('Sandbox Name: ' + context.sandboxName());
        } 
        // Insert logic here to prepare the sandbox for use.
    }
}
```

and then execute anonymous

```
new PrepareMySandbox().runApexClass(null);
```

Type `SandboxContext` can't be constructed so your code, if you want to test in execute anonymous can't depend on a non-null `context`